# Overscroll effect doesn't appear in my recyclerview inside swiperefreshlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overscroll

I have a fragment that contain a SwipeRefreshLayour with a RecyclerView inside.

This recyclerView doesn't show overscroll effects. I tried a lot of things like use this:

```
 android:isScrollContainer="true"
 android:overScrollMode="always"
```

Custom color via styles doesn't work

fadingEdge, fadingEdgeLengh, requiresFadingEdge...

Swipe to refresh is working and it shows this:

[image]

I don't get this:

[image]

Comment: It would really help to answer if you could post your layout and activity/fragment code, (or at least the relevant parts to this issue).

Comment: It is not a layout or code problem, I created a default activity with overscroll via android studio templates (ScrollingActivity), and in my app it hasn't overscroll effects.

Comment: Okay, I created a new app with the default ScrollingActivity and now it hasn't overscroll when a older app of this same ScrollingActivity has overscroll, I am using Android Studio 3.0 beta 2 with the lastest support library. Maybe it is causing this bug?

Comment: The default is working for me

Comment: hold on i will post a video. Keep in mind you need to have velocity for it to trigger. I am using the latest version of android studio as well

Comment: I failed, with Android 2.3.3 it has overscroll effects. It is a bug caused by Android Studio 3.0 beta 2

Comment: Ok i see I am using 2.3.3. But here it is working anyways https://giphy.com/gifs/1Zw0ZeTP8tljq

Comment: I am going to report this bug. One question, do you know how to force to show always overscroll. For example, if you open Play Store navigation drawer and scroll down you can check what I mean

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it by overwriting the SwipeRefreshLayout and using it instead of the default implementation:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

class SwipeRefreshLayoutWithRecyclerViewOverscroll : SwipeRefreshLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, nestedScrollAxes: Int): Boolean =
        (child.canScrollVertically(1) && super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes))

}
```

I'm using a RecyclerView that is a linear vertical list and `child.canScrollVertically(1)` checks wether this list is currently at the very bottom. If it is at the bottom of the list onStartNestedScroll returns false, allowing the RecyclerView to handle the pull up motion of the user so that an overscroll effect is shown.

NOTE: This only shows the bottom edge overscroll and not the top one, because I don't want to see the pull-to-refresh animation together with the top overscroll edge.

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation of this feature, (the over-scroll is working on both top and bottom), I have my layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<...<custom view>...SwipeRefreshWrapper
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/video_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <include layout="@layout/include_video_list_empty_view"/>
        <include layout="@layout/include_watchlist_empty_view"/>

    </FrameLayout>
<SwipeRefreshWrapper>
```

And my SwipeRefreshWrapper implementation is as follows:

```
/**
* This Class ensures that a SwipeRefreshLayout will only refresh if the
* list it wraps cannot scroll up anymore, (that it is at the top). Otherwise
* when the user attempts to scroll up from the middle of the list, the refresh
* will trigger. This is necessary for custom List implementations, (or
* RecyclerViews), only.
*/
public class SwipeRefreshWrapper extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
     private ScrollResolver mScrollResolver;

     public SwipeRefreshWrapper(Context context) {
         super(context);
     }

     public SwipeRefreshWrapper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
     }

     public void setScrollResolver(ScrollResolver scrollResolver) {
         mScrollResolver = scrollResolver;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
         if(mScrollResolver != null){
             return mScrollResolver.canScrollUp();
         } else {
             return super.canChildScrollUp();
         }
     }

     public static interface ScrollResolver{
         public boolean canScrollUp();
     }
}
```

Then in my Fragment I setup the SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
 /**
 * Initializes PullToRefresh handler
 */
private void initPullToRefresh() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshWrapper) mView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorAccent);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setScrollResolver(new SwipeRefreshWrapper.ScrollResolver() {
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollUp() {
            return mVideoRecycler.canScrollVertically(-1);
        }
    });

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(...)
}
```

Comment: I created a scrolling activity and even this activity, with nested scroll, hasn't overscroll.

I don't understand why I have no overscroll effects on my app

Comment: In menus with a lot of items I have overscroll effects, so it is only on activities elements like recyclerview or nestedscrollview

Comment: Can you post your code for this activity? Are you overriding the scroll events perhaps?

Comment: I have no override any scroll on this activity. It just a nested scrollview with a few elements to show some texts. Really a simple activity. There is no scroll word even it the java file.

Comment: I created a scrollingactivity via template with zero changes (I know 100% this activity has overscroll) and in my app hasn't it, so it should be a style problem no?

Comment: Your scroll view should only have 1 child element, this could be your issue. In the example I posted, I have a framelayout that holds the recyclerview and some extra views.

Comment: it is the default scrolling activity, you can create by yourself in Android Studio if you want to check it has overscroll but mine no.

Comment: If you are using  a recyclerview, why do you need a scrollview? I see that the default activity uses a NestedScrollView.

Comment: It is other activity, I think is a bug on Android Studio 3.0 beta 2 or the lastest support libraries, no one scrollview/recycler view of any of my new apps have overscroll.

Comment: I am guessing if you added views to the sample that you still have the NestedScrollView as the root view, try making your ScrollView the root view and see if that fixes the issue. See here for an example: http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/

Comment: You do not need a scroll view around a recycler view, it handles its own scrolling. The NestedScrollView is specifically for the instance of putting a ScrollView inside of another ScrollView. Try removing the root scrollview and let the list do the scrolling

Comment: I created a new app of scrolling activity (check it by yourself in Android Studio), default scrolling activity, zero changes. It hasn't overscroll. This same app in the past had overscroll 100% for sure. it has to be a bug.

Comment: It works for me. This is taken from the [documentation for ScrollViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) **Never add a RecyclerView or ListView to a scroll view. Doing so results in poor user interface performance and a poor user experience.**